# Access an array from another Typescript file

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have an array `DPS` in one of my Typescript files that is not defined in a class in that file, it's just sitting by itself.

```
const DPS: DataTable[] = [
  { tDataPoint: "d1", tICCP: "i1", tStartDate: "s1", tEndDate: "e1" },
  { tDataPoint: "d2", tICCP: "i2", tStartDate: "s2", tEndDate: "e2" },
  { tDataPoint: "d3", tICCP: "i3", tStartDate: "s3", tEndDate: "e3" },
  { tDataPoint: "d4", tICCP: "i4", tStartDate: "s4", tEndDate: "e4" }
];
```

In another Typescript file in a different component directory I want to access this array to manipulate it.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Gavin tried importing the class that contains that array into the other Typescript file but 1. It gives me many console errors and 2. Since that array is not actually part of that class that I'm trying to import, the importing won't do any good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to add `export` before `const` when declaring the variable array. Then import the variable into the other Typescript file `import { DPS } from '../mainpage/mainpage.component';`. Then all I wanted to do with that array was delete an entry so to manipulate that array I just used dot notation. `DPS.splice(0,1);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `export const DPS: DataTable[]`.